# Parsing a 2 GB file giving segmentation fault Error

Tags: perl, parsing, xml-twig

I have written a perl code to filter the XML based on one condition.Its error-out with Message "Segmentation fault (Core Dumped)" with 2GB input file. Please see the below code. Any inputs will be helpful.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Tie::File;
use XML::Parser;

my $SOURCEFILE=$ARGV[0];
my $TAGVALUE=$ARGV[1];
my $FILELOCATIONIN=$ARGV[2];




my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );

$twig->parsefile($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'.xml');

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');

$twig->print_to_file($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'.xml');

sub TRADE {
    my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
    foreach  my $c ($TRADE)
        {
        #added delete in place of cut
#$TRADE->cut
         $c->delete($TRADE) unless
         $c->att('origin') eq $TAGVALUE

      ;
    }
}
```

Comment: any informations about your system would be helpful. Furthermore there is a bug noted in `XML::Twig` when your perl version is lower than 5.16

Comment: @Patrick J. S..    The version of Perl is v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: @Patrick J. S  Any help would be helpful....

Comment: upgrade your perl, or read up the Bug description (in the docs of that module), there was some flag that might help you, but will break other things.

Comment: Can you please include a sample of your xml data?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to overwrite the input file as you're reading it, use `->parsefile_inplace();`

```
my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );
$twig->parsefile_inplace($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'.xml');
```

Comment: Right, the memory issues are caused by the bug in perl as @Patrick said.  http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm#BUGS